# How to asynchronously memory stream pdf to an IFrame in C# Web API?

Tags: c#, pdf, iframe, asynchronous

I have an issue. Currently, my code in Web Api controller sends a HttpResponseMessage back to the browser as follows:

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

MemoryStream stream = ConvertWordToPdf(document.Path);

response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.GetBuffer()); 

response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.GetBuffer().Length;

return response;
```

However, for performance, I would like to use streaming or an async approach (unlike this one that doesn't). So, instead of waiting for all the bytes to load into memory and then streaming them to the client, I would like to start to stream the http response to the client as it is loaded after conversion.

So, I work with a memory stream which does not have a physical file (that does not matter right?). I have attempted to use StreamContent and PushStreamContent but I cannot get it work. I can get it to download the file as an attachment which I do not want. It needs to update in an IFrame like the non-async one does:

```
< iframe src="{{url}}" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="660px"/>
```

If it's any use, the convert function is as follows:

```
public MemoryStream ConvertWordToPdf(string id)
{
    var wordFilename = id;

    var reds = new RichEditDocumentServer();

    reds.LoadDocument(wordFilename, DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.DocumentFormat.OpenXml);

    var ms = new MemoryStream();

    reds.ExportToPdf(ms);

    return ms;
}
```

**EDIT**

To clarify, changing the response snippet above, to the following does not make any noticeable performance difference and has no implication for an async equivalent anyway:

```
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

                var stream = ConvertWordToPdf(document.Path);

                var bytes = stream.ToArray();

                response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);

                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

                response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

                return response;
```

The would expect the following to work as async but the pdf does not display content in the IFrame:

```
                                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

                var stream = ConvertWordToPdf(document.Path);

                var bytes = stream.ToArray();

                response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);

                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

                response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

                return response;
```

Also, substituting the ContentType for the following results in the document being downloaded outside the IFrame which is not the purpose of this exercise:

```
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
```

Comment: Are you are thinking the pdf will be incrementally displayed? This would only work if the Pdf is designed for it (fast Web view or linearized pdfs)

Comment: Yes, incrementally; how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Consider in particular this line of your current code:

```
response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.GetBuffer().Length;
```

You set a header line (i.e. a line that is to be sent before you can start sending your actual PDF) with the size of the PDF you create.

You do not know the exact size before you finish generating the PDF.

As long as you want to set this header, therefore, you cannot start sending the PDF before it is completely generated.

Several questions here on stackoverflow suggest that at least certain browser versions require the `ContentLength` header to work properly.

Thus, you cannot implement your objective.

---

As an aside, you return `stream.GetBuffer()` (and accordingly set the size above to `stream.GetBuffer().Length`). This is wrong, though. Have a look at the remark on the msdn page on the [MemoryStream.GetBuffer Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Note that the buffer contains allocated bytes which might be unused. For example, if the string "test" is written into the `MemoryStream` object, the length of the buffer returned from `GetBuffer` is 256, not 4, with 252 bytes unused. To obtain only the data in the buffer, use the `ToArray` method; however, `ToArray` creates a copy of the data in memory.

In your case, therefore, you may have several trailing trash bytes appended to the PDF.

Thus, you should instead use `ToArray` or (taking resources into account, cf. the final sentence of the quote) transmission methods that only process part of a `byte[]` and limit them to the first `stream.Length` bytes of `stream.GetBuffer()`.

Comment: Even if ToArray() was sufficient, how is what you propose async? The snippet I include is clearly synchronous, as pointed out in the question. You're not answering the question.

Comment: I did answer insofar as sync is no improvement for you. You cannot start transmitting before you sent the `ContentLength` header. For that header you need the actual PDF size. You don't know the size before the PDF is completely created. Thus, you will have to cache anyways. By making things async, you would, therefore, make it slower if anything.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you decided not to need the `ContentLength` header anymore, async would be an improvement.

Comment: `@Carnotaurus Thus, do you need the `ContentLength` header or not?

Comment: I appear to need it at least so that it renders in the iframe

Comment: Ok, so there is nothing to gain from making it asynchronous.

Comment: How would it work if I didn't need the ContentLength?

Comment: I investigated a bit into the `HttpContent` classes (you after all have to set an instance of one to `response.Content`) but the asynchronous usage of them seems to restrict to *reading* from them (i.e. what a HTTP client needs to do) and not include asynchronously *writing* to them which code on the server side would need. Probably I overlooked something, though...

Comment: That's a shame but thanks anyway; I'll leave it as it is until technologies improve... Are you any good with url rewriting? I've something weird going on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745476/how-do-i-get-the-macclesfield-rewrite-rule-to-redirect-to-the-correct-url